# Ways to make printing (on real, tangible paper) an Rmd prettier?

Tags: r, printing, r-markdown

I find that looking at an Rmd as an HTML on a screen is nice because you can scroll through and use all the interactive bits. But when I want to actually print out an Rmd with the code visible, even short tasks tend to take up quite a bit of space and many sheets of paper. Even the defualt Rmd that pops up in rstudio that plots cars takes up an entire page. Granted, you could make the plot a lot smaller and save some space. But with some more complicated and formatted code, you start to take up a lot of space quite quickly. Is there some better way to format these so that they take up less paper? The colored code in the digital form would be nice too.

Yes I agree that sending people the digital version is probably better but some people I work with insist on print outs.

Comment: I thought there were print-to-pdf functions?

Comment: Have a look at the PDF output formats provided by `tufte`, `tint` and `pinp` packages on CRAN.